# How to deal with errors for loading a rdata file?

Tags: r

I need the data of the .rdata file for text mining. These are my dataset. I don't know exactly what's in that file. The problem is i can't load it.

I tried to open the file with different windows computers but with the same errors. I used RStudio in the updated version. I google the error-Information but nothing worked. Because I can open other rdata files there should be no registry problem. I wanted to check in an other basic windows  Editor to look what is in the file but there were only signs like: ‹      ìùuPo³6
’@p ÜÝ‚»»»[pw—…»»»»»†àînÁuA°E`!‡ßûîýí}æÌLMÕÌùæŸÝõTñÈ}÷ÝrõÕ½
¢hXˆ
I tried different possibilities to open the file in RStudio with different error informations as followed:

with load()

```
require("readr")
setwd("C:/Users/..")
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
load("file")
# Error in load("file") : 
#   bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
# In addition: Warning message:
# file ‘.rdata’ has magic number ''
#   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

with source()

```
require("readr")
setwd("C:/Users/..")
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
source("file")
# Error in source("file") : 
#   file.rdata:1:1: unexpected input
# 1: 
#     ^
```

readRDS

```
setwd("C:/Users/..")
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
readRDS("file")
# Error in readRDS("file") : unknown input format
```

Comment: How was that `rdata` file created exactly? It doesn't sound like it's a format that R can recognize. (You an make a file with any extension you want.)

Comment: I don't know it exactly. It's a part of a big dataset. It was programmed with R and contain scraped and parsed data of websites. There should only be date and text. That's all I know. It was said to me that other people could open their parts.

Comment: Then I would ask those that prepared it how it's meant to be read. The file could contain literally anything.

Comment: Sorry, I have not that much experience with R. What information would I need and how would it change the code? Is it more an encoding problem or what kind of problem is it?
Maybe a stupid question by myself but I don't get - how can RStudio not recognize an obviously in R written rdata file?

Comment: Ideally you would just ask them how to import the file they created for you. Or at the very least ask what function was used to create the file. Normally "rdata" files are created with `save()` and you should be able to use `load()` to import them. But the error message implies it's not a "true" rdata file. You can name a file whatever you want; just because its named "rdata" doesn't mean it's obviously a R written rdata file. I'm not sure how you got the data to your computer but it's possible it could have been corrupted on transfer. Impossible to say without the data though.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for the explanation. I get it with an E-Mail and now that you mentioned it he was confused (I already told him about the problem) that I don't open it with load(). He send me other rdata files which I couldn't open as well. Maybe there is a problem with my download of the files (whatever this problem could be)